# Cordova Android build error “Cannot read property 'version' of null”

Tags: angularjs, angular, cordova

I'm trying to run the the cordova build Android command and it's failing. Error message output:

```
$> cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Android (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android (DEPRECATED)
Cannot read property 'version' of null
```

I have the latest version of cordova, gradle and the Java 8 JDK installed. And all the environments are set. I have no idea what could be the issue.

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-07-02 12:16:43 UTC
Revision:     774525a055494e0ece39f522ac7ad17498ce032c

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_301 (Oracle Corporation 25.301-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

$ cordova --version
10.0.0

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing and re-adding the platform resolved my issue.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```